# Python nested json parsing and splitting the values

Tags: python, json

I am trying to split and assign the url's to the variable, I am getting the desired result but I know there is a way where I can improvise the current code.

**JSON FILE**

```
{
"Result": [
"Url::Link::Url1",
"Url::Link::Url2",
"Url::Link::Url3",
"Url::Link::Url4",
"Url::Link::Url5",
"Url::Link::Url6",
"Url::Link::Url7"
],
"Record": [
"Record::Label::Music1",
"Record::Label::Music2",
"Record::Label::Music3"
],
}
```

```
import requests
import json

url = "http:mywebsite.com"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': "PostmanRuntime/7.15.2",
    'Accept': "*/*",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache"
    }

result= requests.get("GET", url, headers=headers).json()
url1 = []
url2 = []
url3 = []

for i in result['Result'][0:1]:
    url1.append(i.split('::')[2])

for i in result['Result'][1:2]:
    url1.append(i.split('::')[2])

for i in result['Result'][2:3]:
    url1.append(i.split('::')[2])
```

**Output**
url1=Url1
url2=Url2
...

Answer (score 2):

As long as there's nothing special about the *n*th URL, you can just store the URLs in one list:

```
urls = []

for result_string in result["Result"]:
    url = result_string.split("::")[2]
    urls.append(url)
```

If there is something unique information you want to capture about the *n*th URL, you could store the URLs in a dictionary to map the URL to its type.

```
def url_type(n):
    """returns the type of url given its index n in the response"""

    #example
    if n == 1:
        return 'url-type-a'

    return 'url-type-b'   


urls = {
    "url-type-a": [],
    "url-type-b": []
}


for i, result_string in enumerate(result["Result"]):

    url = result_string.split("::")[2]
    urls[url_type(i)].append(url)
```